# Embed Facebook Customer Chat Plugin without creating a Facebook app

Tags: facebook, web, plugins, chat, messenger

It seems in order to embed Facebook Customer Chat Plugin, dev has to create a custom Facebook app to act as hook receiver to be called from the embed. The flow is somehow this way:

**Embed on browser** ---custom app id,page id---> **Custom web server** ---page access token,text response--> **Facebook Messenger Server** --> Back to Embed on browser.

This is good for making a chatbot but can it be simpler to chat directly between visitor and a Facebook page owner, this way:?

**Embed on browser** ---Messenger app id,page id---> **Facebook Messenger Server** ---> **Page owner on Messenger.com** ---text response--> Embed on browser.

Facebook Message Us Plugin and m.me link are other options but overlay embed (Customer Chat Plugin) is more interesting as visitors can chat right on the web page.

PS.
m.me link is nice on Android, it opens Messenger app.